# "DB2OLEDB provider is not registered on the local machine" exception in C# code...accessing DB2 database from C#

Tags: c#, db2

I am attempting to connect to DB2 database from C#.Net. The connection string i used is:

Provider=DB2OLEDB;Cache Authentication=True;Password=xxxxxxx;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxxxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxxxxxx;Data Source=xxxxxxxxx;Defer Prepare=False;Derive Parameters=False;Network Transport Library=TCPIP;Host CCSID=37;PC Code Page=1252;Network Address=xxxxxxxxx;Network Port=446;Package Collection=CDATA;Default Schema=CDATA;DBMS Platform=DB2/AS400;Process Binary as Character=False;Connection Pooling=True;Units of Work=RUW

On executing the ExecuteReader(), i keep getting the runtime exception:

**The 'DB2OLEDB' provider isn't registered on the local system.**

I have already included the reference to library "System.Data.OleDb" in my class.
The DB2 resides on a different server and i don't have any db2 instance on my local machine. How do I solve this difficulty?

Can someone please help me with fixing this error, is it any other dll reference that I am missing? I am assuming I do not need to get any DB2 client installaed on my machine in order to be fixing this issue, could it be done by just a dll reference?

Answer (score 0):

Change the provider name from "DB2OLEDB" to "IBMDADB2" and see also here: [IBM Knowledge Center](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSNY3_10.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.adonet.doc/doc/c0011825.html)